# Connecting Ubuntu 14.04 and OS X 10.10.3 Via Ethernet Cable

Tags: 14.04, networking, ethernet

I have got a PC running Ubuntu 14.04.02 and an iMac running OS X 10.10.3
Now , I have got some big files ( >500 gigs) on both the machines . I would like to establish an ethernet connection between these two machines , so that i can transfer files from both the machines . But as i am quite new to linux , i don't quite know how to do it . Please,help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As sharing the folders which containing the files is possible scenario i recommend samba configuration on ubuntu which will setup shared folder due to which you can simply copy paste whichever file you like from both ubuntu to mac or vice-versa

[samba installation in ubuntu](https://www.maketecheasier.com/install-and-configure-samba-in-ubuntu-for-file-sharing/)